# Git: How do I move one changed file to a new branch that is already committed?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have 2 changed files committed on a branch, pushed to origin. How do I move 1 changed file to another branch?

I have tried the following steps (starting on dev branch with 2 files already added, commited, pushed). Reseting the file, stashing it, and switching to a new branch, **I would expect to be able to apply my stash. It does not work. What am I missing here / what am I doing wrong?**

```
$ git checkout origin/master filename
$ git reset HEAD filename
$ git stash
$ git checkout master
$ git checkout -b new_branch
$ git stash apply stash@{0}
  # On branch new_branch
  nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Comment: If this is a stupid question please tell me why

Comment: I'm probably just missing a piece of high level information here

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something on this page will help: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing

There is a `git stash branch` command that it mentions.

Answer (score 0):

you can checkout the file to a specific commit:

`git checkout <COMMIT_SHA> path/to/file`

to revert back to the current file

`git checkout HEAD path/to/file`